# Articulate storyline Ordering Results

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, articulate-storyline

For an Articulate Storyline project I would like to order my results from High to Low and display only the top 5.

Does someone know how you can do this in Articulate Storyline or Javascript?

Comment: You should show the code you've tried so far. See [How-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about:
**1. Triggers.**
**2. Variables.**
**1.** You can use [triggers](https://community.articulate.com/series/articulate-storyline-1/articles/adding-and-editing-triggers) to perform actions based on a condition - for example:

> **Show** image_1 on **mouseover** of button_1

Simply attach the trigger to the object you want to be affected and choose which condition affects it.
The triggers will execute in the same order they are placed in the trigger panel at the top right of the screen.
**2.** Now, about ordering the results, you will need to test if a result is bigger than the next result, and if it is, place it at the top of the list.
For this you will need to assign each result to a [variable](https://community.articulate.com/series/articulate-storyline-1/articles/working-with-variables).
[image]
There are 3 types of variable in Storyline:

- Text
- Number
- True/False

You want **Number** as the results are numbers.

Now you have variables that represent each of your results, you need to test them against each other to determine the order from **high to low.** 
You can display results as textboxes depending on their value using triggers to compare results.